# How to configure web.xml for multiple login in a Struts2 web application?

Tags: java, authentication, struts2, web.xml

I would like to develop a small test multi-login application using Struts2 and JSP. Basically:

1. The application should have welcome page (i.e. `index.jsp`) anyone can access.
2. This welcome page would have two login boxes: one for users and one for administrators.
3. The web application should have two sub-applications, one for users, one for administrator. In other words, it is not a single application where logged-in users would have different privileges. Each sub-application would have their own secluded set of pages.

Struts2 uses the MVC pattern and I am wondering how I should use the filter pattern to organize this. I could have all requests under `/userapp/*` go to the user application and all requests under `/adminapp/*` go to the admin application.

My questions are:

1. Is this the right strategy (i.e. best practice)? If yes, how should I implement this in my `web.xml`?
2. Should I implement two filters and two mappings (if yes why?) or should I implement one filter and two mappings?

**UPDATE**

After doing a lot of reading, I get to understand that Struts2 multi-login is an over-engineered and too heavy solution for what I need. I have decided to implement my own Servlet 3.0 and use JQuery + Ajax.

Comment: What do you mean by sub-application?Is that 2 web-application within a parent?

Comment: @Max_dev That is also what I am trying to find out too. Should I implement two separate applications rather than trying to put them under the same parent? I am not really sure what the best practice is...

Comment: @ JVerstry:Instead of writing 2 separate web-apps, you should try structure your class hierarchies to a well-defined structure(which is extensible,resuable,etc).And,writing 2 separate web-apps for a single web-app is irrelevant(Unless, you have two different site integration,idk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a case where there are 2 different users 'Admin'(Highest Privileges) and 'Customer(Less Privileges compared to Admin)'. In Struts,you can implement like this

1.Make a Business Logic like `User` class which basically does the following tasks

```
  a.)Gets the username,password as input.
  b.)Checks whether this 'username' exists in database.
  c.)If exits, gets the type of user(either Admin or Customer) and checking 
     its corresponding password.
```

2.Use this 'User' object from within 'Action' class.So,you pass the 'ActionForm' values(username,password) into this business method,validate the user and get a specific usertype(Storing in session).

3.On subsequent requests made by this 'User',check the usertype and forward accordingly.Create a custom 'Action' class which always validates the usertype(and other validations) on each action received from a usertype. **All your other 'Action' class should extend this custom 'Action' class.**

This is how i implemented in one of the my Struts web-application where more than 3 types of users with different rights.I never seen a separate url pattern for each user type.So it is better to show,
  `http://www.yoursite.com/Process.action` 
   instead of `http://www.yoursite.com/adminapp/Process.action`